# Replace occurrences of NSString - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, replace, nsstring

I have a long NSString in which I m trying to replace special characters. Part of my string looks like this:

```
"veau (c\u00f4telette)","veau (filet)","agneau (gigot)","agneau (c\u00f4telette)","b**\u0153**uf (hach\u00e9)","porc (hach\u00e9)"
```

I would like to replace all the \u0153 with "oe". I've tried:

```
[response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u0153" withString:@"oe"];
```

but it doesn't work.... I don't understand why!

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The backslash is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character), so if you want to specify the actual backslash character in a string literal, you need to use two backslashes.

```
NSString *new = [old stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\u0153" withString:@"oe"];
```

Comment: what if i have to replace two different components of the string like "veau" and "u0153"

Answer (score 9):

NSString is immutable, so the function generates a new string that you have to store:

```
NSString *new = [old stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u0153" withString:@"oe"];
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention this is already the case... still doesn't work!